# Is there some kind of symbology saved in a GPX track?

Tags: gpx

I know there can we can save some kind of symbology for waypoints into the GPX files, but I began doubting about the track symbols. I checked the GPX format specifications but I wanted to make sure.

Can it contain information about symbol width, color or something like that?

Comment: What did you find from the schema? Track is like http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/#type_trkType. It contains Track Segments http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/#type_trksegType, which seems to contain points which are of type Waypoint http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/#type_wptType. So track points can have anything that waypoints can, including <sym> xsd:string </sym>.

Comment: I read the same information as you posted. This is exactly what I understood from it. So I guess that confirms that I am not crazy!